# Writing a unittest

Tags: unit-testing, python-unittest

I am very new in python programming and trying to learn unittest currently.
I had wrote a program called Current_age.py and wanting to write a unittest for this, in which i don't know how. So please help me. Though i have given it a try but it does not work as i expected.

Current_age.py

```
import datetime
def age(birthday):
   todays = datetime.date(2001, 5, 12)
   yyyy = int(birthday[0:4])
   mm = int(birthday[4:6])
   dd = int(birthday[6:8])

   date_of_birth = datetime.date(yyyy,mm,dd)
   age_in_day = (todays - date_of_birth).days
   age_in_years = round(age_in_day/365)

   return age_in_years
```

And then i wrote a unittest file which called test_age

```
import unittest
import Current_age
class test_age(unittest.TestCase):
    def Test_Learning_classes_age(self):
       self.assertEqual(Current_age.age("20000315"), 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
   unittest.main()
```

I use VS Code and had created a Virtual Environment and run the code straight on Vs Code because it is easier. So when i ran the code, it said

```
0 test ran in 0.00s
Ok
```

Please help me on this.

Hello there everyone, thank for commencing on the program.

I have try to rename some of the methods and classes with the files. And it work. But i really don't know where is the difference so if you can please help me spot it.

The first file is called Age.py which store the function.

```
import datetime
def age(birthday):
    todays = datetime.date(2001, 5, 12)
    yyyy = int(birthday[0:4])
    mm = int(birthday[4:6])
    dd = int(birthday[4:6]
    

    date_of_birth = datetime.date(yyyy, mm, dd)
    age_in_day = (todays - date_of_birth).days
    age_in_years = round(age_in_day / 365)

    return age_in_years
```

And then i created another file to test the function which called Testage.py

```
import Age
import unittest

class Testage(unittest.Testcase):
     def test_age(self):
         self.assertEqual(Age.age("19710113"), 30)
         self.assertEqual(Age.age("20000712"), 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

And another question which is also related to unittest. Can i create a unittest that of a function which have user input()? And if it is possible how shall I do it? Thanks.

Comment: [Per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example): “individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the letters `test`”. Perhaps the **test method’s name should confirm to the lower case convention**. Additionally, class names in Python are conventionally `CamelCase`, so the class name should be `TestAge`.

Comment: Additionally, in the posted code, I don’t see `Learning_classes` being defined.

Comment: Perhaps it’s worth reviewing the [Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id32) section of PEP8, as there are a few conventions broken in the posted code.

Comment: Where does `Learning_classes` come from? Please provide complete, minimal code

Answer (score 0):

Improved and corrected version of your code:

```
from Age import age
import unittest

class TestAge(unittest.Testcase):
     def test_age(self):
         self.assertEqual(Age.age("19710113"), 30)
         self.assertEqual(Age.age("20000712"), 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

And regarding your question, unit tests are not really designed to accept user input.